# Python created dictionary truncating output for a large dataset. How do I save the full dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I inherited this code which is used to format and read a model output.  However, when I run it and save the output to a text file it only gives the first 5 lines and last five lines for each location (dictionary key).  I am not sure if it is a problem in the code or the settings.  I am running the code in Jupyter notebook.  Attached is the code and the output.

```
def outflw1(path=''):
    #get the starting year (old outflw1 format)
    if path == '':
        fin1 = open('input')
    else:
        fin1 = open(os.path.join(path, 'input'))
    s = fin1.readline()
    while 'starting date of simulation' not in s:
        s = fin1.readline()
    s = s.replace(' ','').split(',')
    year = int(s[2][:4])
    fin1.close()
    #read off 5 lines - don't need them.  These are the headers and blank lines in the file
    f = open(os.path.join(path,'outflw1'))
    for i in range(5):
        next(f)
    #create dictionary for StringIO
    sio = {} #denotes as a dictionary object
    init = 0

    for ln in f:
        if not ln.strip():
            init = 1
            if s[0] == '12' and s[1] == '31' and s[2] == '23.0':
                year += 1
            continue
        else:
            s = ln.split()
            #if first time through need to initialize StringIO objects
            if init == 0:
                sio[s[3]] = StringIO()
                sio[s[3]].write(str(year) + '-' + s[0] + '-' + s[1] + ' ' + s[2].split('.')[0] + ':00:00' + ',')
            else:
                sio[s[3]].write(str(year) + '-' + s[0] + '-' + s[1] + ' ' + s[2].split('.')[0] + ':00:00' + ',')
            sio[s[3]].write(','.join(s[4:8]) + ',')
            if len(s) == 11:
                sio[s[3]].write(','.join(s[9:]) + '\n')
            else:
                sio[s[3]].write(','.join([s[8][2:],s[9]]) + '\n')
            continue

    outflw1 = {}

    for k in list(sio.keys()):
        sio[k].seek(0)
        outflw1[k] = pd.read_csv(sio[k], parse_dates=True, index_col=0,
               names = ['tide', 'elevation', 'depth', 'velocity', 'direction', 'salinity'])
        outflw1[k].index.name = 'Date'

    return(outflw1)
```

Here is the output for one of the keys.  It looks the same when I use the print command and save it to a text file.

```
{'10018':                      tide  elevation  depth  velocity  direction  salinity
 Date                                                                      
 1987-1-1 :00:00      0.40       0.06   3.06      0.01     121.87      8.48
 1987-1-1 1:00:00    -0.47       0.09   3.09      0.02     122.65      8.50
 1987-1-1 2:00:00    -1.54       0.13   3.13      0.03     134.67      8.51
 1987-1-1 3:00:00    -1.83       0.18   3.18      0.02     133.44      8.53
 1987-1-1 4:00:00    -1.75       0.21   3.21      0.01     334.74      8.55
 ...                   ...        ...    ...       ...        ...       ...
 2014-12-31 20:00:00  0.87       1.33   4.33      0.04     128.71     24.77
 2014-12-31 21:00:00  0.86       1.40   4.40      0.05     169.77     24.84
 2014-12-31 22:00:00  0.92       1.45   4.45      0.05     168.49     24.90
 2014-12-31 23:00:00  1.02       1.37   4.37      0.03     311.43     24.91
 2015-1-1 :00:00      0.97       1.34   4.34      0.02     161.63     24.93
 
 [245449 rows x 6 columns],
```

Comment: It's probably Jupyter, not the code. It's abbreviating the output so that it can fit into a reasonable amount of space.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use pickle module to serialize:

```
pickle.dump
```

Comment: I tried pickle.dump but it did not work.  I tried messing with the max rows setting in Panda again and this time it worked.  Apparently I was off in how many rows I needed and it kept truncating the same way until I got the number right.